# Complex regex up to 30 chars

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex in order to pull from a sentence only the once that fit within the first 30 chars. some use case could be a word that exceed the 30 chars so i like to break it into two outputs.

Simple example:

```
Verwaltungsgesetze
```

Output should be

```
Verwaltungsgesetze
```

Another simple one:

```
Gesetze des Landes Berlin
```

Output should be:

```
Gesetze des Landes Berlin
```

One that is more complex :

```
Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte
```

I like the output to be separated into two results

```
1. Deutsche
2. Gesellschaftsgeschichte
```

The reason is because the word Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte is total of 33 chars but it doesn't make sense to cut it after 30 chars so it makes more sense to break it into two parts.

I have used this to find chars up to 30 but I don't know how to know how to support the last case I have described.

`^(?=.{1,30}$)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should happen with `Donaudampfschiffahrtskapitänspatent` (or other words that are longer than 30 characters?

Comment: Don't match it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to look at this problem from the end: You want to match whitespace or the end of the string as the last thing of your regular expression. Before that, there needs to be the start of the string or where the last match left off, and between that at most 30 characters.

```
((^|\G).{0,30})( |$)
```

This matches the input data as follows:

```
Verwaltungsgesetze
                  ^
Gesetze des Landes Berlin
                         ^
Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte
        ^
Donaudampfschiffahrtskapitänspatent
(no match)
```

For the edge case of words longer than 30 characters, you will get no match at all.

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/IiOi4x/2)

Comment: for the word - Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte
it does only take the Deutsche, I want it also to give me Gesellschaftsgeschichte as second result. it doesn't seems to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer - you need to do a global match and you (likely) want to continue from the last match `\G`

Comment: didn't work for me. sorry. the other solution did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my example to get the text:

```js
let str_input = `Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte
Gesetze des Landes Berlin
Gesetze des Landes Berlinxxxxxx`;

let arr_input = str_input.split("\n");
let regex = /(?=^.{31,}$)(\w+)\s([\w ]+)|(?=^.{1,30}$)([\w ]+)/;
for(let i=0; i<arr_input.length; i++){
  let temp_str = arr_input[i];
  temp_str.replace(regex, function(match,text1,text2){
    if(text2){
      console.log(`Case 2: Text is over 30 character. \nContent1=${text1} \nContent2=${text2}`);
    }else{
      console.log(`Case 1: Text is in 30 character. Content=${match}`);
    }
  });
}
```

Look detail in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ydjwB6/1

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I have one problem. it doesn't support ü for example. how can it be supported?

Comment: You can list these special characters in character set. Like this: `(?=^.{31,}$)([\wü]+)\s([\w ü]+)|(?=^.{1,30}$)([\w ü]+)` . See: https://regex101.com/r/ydjwB6/2

Comment: This works, I have added. is there a way to limit it to up 90 chars?

Comment: To limit use quantifier `{min,max}`. Example: `(?=^.{31,90}$)([\wü]+)\s([\w ü]+)|(?=^.{1,30}$)([\w ü]+)`. See: https://regex101.com/r/ydjwB6/3/

Comment: One thing that doesn't work for me, this inoput - Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte Gesetze des Landes Berlin . doesn't break it in the correct place. the first part is 'Deutsche' and the rest is in part 2.

Comment: Because in ` Deutsche Gesellschaftsgeschichte Gesetze des Landes Berlin` has a space before `Deutsche`. But in our regex, we didn't defined it!